# SimpleModal JS height is more then browser height is not scrollable

Tags: javascript, jquery, simplemodal

I am using [SimpleModal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) for a project. But i am facing an issue when the simplemodal dialog box **height** is more than **document height** it's not scrollable. It's cut from the bottom.

I have search about it's but nothing works.

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this is what you want...

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    $('#basic-modal .basic').click(function (e) {

       $('#basic-modal-content').modal();
       $("#simplemodal-container").css({ 'position' : 'absolute'});  
       $(".simplemodal-wrap").removeAttr('style');
       return false;
    });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it's create  scrollbar inside the dialog box not outside

Comment: you want the scrollbar outside the modal? do you want to scroll the container window?

Comment: Yes, i want on container window